# How to create an Enum to use with Grails

Tags: grails, enums

Grails 2.2

So this should be pretty easy, however I am constantly getting the same error message:

```
Class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message No enum constant myPackageName.RequestType.Banner
```

Here is my class:

```
public enum RequestType {
    BANNER("Banner"), OTHER("Other")

    final String value

    RequestType(String value) { this.value = value }

    String toString() { value }
}
```

This is driving me up the wall!!

Edit: Stacktrace

```
No enum constant myPackageName.RequestType.Banner. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant myPackageName.RequestType.Banner
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.methodMissing(GormStaticApi.groovy:108)
    at ysuprojects.ProjectService.viewableProjects(ProjectService.groovy:115)
    at ysuprojects.ProjectService.getIndexModel(ProjectService.groovy:422)
    at ysuprojects.ProjectController.index(ProjectController.groovy:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here is how it is used in the class

```
class Project {
    ...
    RequestType requestType
    ...
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be RequestType.BANNER?

Comment: It is that way everywhere in my code

Comment: hmm what happens if you change `RequestType(String value)` to private? Can you post your stacktrace too?

Comment: Same error if it's private, posting stacktrace now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok - so here is what happened.

I switched from using a `String` to using an `Enum`. The existing database had `"Banner"` in the field, which was causing this error. I changed the field to `"BANNER"` and I no longer receive this error.

Grails was attempting to do `Enum.valueOf(RequestType, "Banner")`